# Trying to figure out the pattern in this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, pattern-recognition

I'm trying to figure out the rule that's producing the series below.  The first column is the factorials $1!,2!,3!,4!,5!,6!$  But I can't figure out what else is going on.  So I know the next row will start with $7!=5040$, but can't say much beyond that.  If someone has insight as to what the next numbers in the series are that would be much appreciated.

$1$

$2\qquad2$

$6\qquad12\qquad6$

$24\qquad72\qquad72\qquad24$

$120\qquad480\qquad720\qquad480\qquad120$

$720\qquad3600\qquad7200\qquad7200\qquad3600\qquad720$

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried dividing each row by the first term?

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=1,2,2,6,12,6,24,72,72,24,120,480,&language=english&go=Search

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Commented while I was posting my answer, d'oh!

Comment: @sdcvvc what a cool website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to find the answer here is to divide out by the first terms, producing:

$$\begin{array}
&&&&&&1\\
&&&&1&&1\\
&&&1&&2&&1\\
&&1&&3&&3&&1\\
&1&&4&&6&&4&&1\\
\end{array}$$
...which should look awfully familiar.  This implies that the $(n,k)$ entry of your series is $n! {n-1 \choose k}$.

Comment: Thanks!  Much clearer now.  Pardon my ignorance but I am not familiar with the notation you used.  What exactly does $n! {n-1 \choose k}$ mean?

Comment: Well, the $n!$ piece of that you already know; $n-1\choose k$ (generally pronounced '$n$-minus-1 choose $k$') is the Binomial Coefficient.  $a\choose b$ is defined as $a!/b!(a-b)!$ and represents the number of ways of choosing b items from a population of a items; they're arguably the most fundamental objects in combinatorics.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient for more details on it!